# How do I add auto bed levelling to my Marlin-based CNC?

Tags: bed-leveling, cnc

I just finished a CNC that uses Marlin Firmware. The dimensions of it are quite large (3200 x 2000 mm) and the table is not perfect. I'm thinking of adding a proximity sensor to store a mesh in the eeprom and thus compensate for any errors. I'm not sure how to do this. I would like to be able to execute an action from the display (full graphics) and have samples taken over the whole table, but I do not know how to tell the firmware where to take the samples, nor what the dimensions of it are.

Comment: Welcome to 3D Printing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Auto bed leveling requires some settings (constants) in the configuration of your Marlin firmware.

It is recommended to [read about the implementation of automatic bed leveling](http://marlinfw.org/docs/features/auto_bed_leveling.html) first. There are a few options to choose the kind of leveling, for 3D printers a commonly chosen option is `AUTO_BED_LEVELING_BILINEAR` which is the best option if you do not know if your bed is flat or not. If you are certain it is flat but tilted (e.g. when you have a milled bed or a glass plate in 3D printing) you could go for `AUTO_BED_LEVELING_3POINT` or `AUTO_BED_LEVELING_LINEAR`.

What further is important is the sensor type you choose. Do you want a touch or a proximity sensor. The latter is your preference (as specified in your question), which is a little simpler as you do not need to configure for servos for deploying and stowing.

You need to set:

```
#define FIX_MOUNTED_PROBE
```

for using a fixed proximity sensor.

In the configuration file you also need to specify the position of the probe in relation to the nozzle (in your case tool center):

```
#define X_PROBE_OFFSET_FROM_EXTRUDER 10  // X offset: -left  +right  [of the nozzle]
#define Y_PROBE_OFFSET_FROM_EXTRUDER 10  // Y offset: -front +behind [the nozzle]
```

and optionally:

```
#define Z_PROBE_OFFSET_FROM_EXTRUDER 0   // Z offset: -below +above  [the nozzle]
```

This latter is not necessary as you can always set the distance of the sensor trigger point to the nozzle/tool plane by G-code command `M851 Z-x.xx`

You would also need to set the boundaries of the probe area to prevent the tool to hit unwanted positions (fill out values or leave the constants):

```
// Set the boundaries for probing (where the probe can reach).
#define LEFT_PROBE_BED_POSITION MIN_PROBE_EDGE
#define RIGHT_PROBE_BED_POSITION (X_BED_SIZE - MIN_PROBE_EDGE)
#define FRONT_PROBE_BED_POSITION MIN_PROBE_EDGE
#define BACK_PROBE_BED_POSITION (Y_BED_SIZE - MIN_PROBE_EDGE)
```

Once properly setup, command [`G29`](http://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/G029-abl.html) runs the leveling of the bed, options are available for that command to store the bed mesh to EEPROM.

Enabling `LCD_BED_LEVELING` constant in the configuration file will add a Bed Leveling sub-menu to the LCD. But you could also work with SD-card stored files that load these codes.

[This](https://3dprint.wiki/reprap/anet/a8/improvement/autobedleveling) reference explains the automatic leveling in more detail, but there are many more detailed guides to follow from the internet. Be sure that you get a recent guide to that is easier to set in the latest firmware.

Comment: Thanks!. Can I uncomment MESH_BED_LEVELING and AUTO_BED_LEVELING_BILINEAR at the same time?. I want to test the result of this manually before going to the automatic solution. With both methods activated, both options will appear on the menu?. (auto and manual).

Comment: No I do not think it is possible, if you look into the config file you see that if you enable both, `AUTO_BED_LEVELING_BILINEAR` is executed is some `#if` statement and it will then never go to the `#elif` of `MESH_BED_LEVELING `.